# inherit only one property in css

Tags: css, inheritance

Let's say we have this:

```
.first-class {
background: purple;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}
.first-class > .second-class {
/* code goes here */
}
```

In .second-class, Is it possible to only inherit one property from first-class, say, background, while leaving the other properties as default?

Comment: This is not about inheritance (which is a specific, well-defined, widely-misunderstood concept in CSS). You seem to want to set some properties as “default”, *overriding* possible inheritance. Please reformulate the question and specify what you mean by “default” (CSS initial value? browser default? value that the property would otherwise have? – three distinct, though somewhat connected, concepts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to reset them. `.first-class` being the parent of `.second-class` will take its inheritance.

Here is the **[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ED9pH/)** to illustrate your scenario before reset.

Now when you **[reset it.](http://jsfiddle.net/ED9pH/1/)**

Find the below code before and after reset.

## Before reset:

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="first-class">
    <div class="second-class">abcd</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.first-class {
background: purple;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}
.first-class > .second-class {
/* code goes here */
}
```

## After Reset:

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="first-class">
    <div class="second-class">abcd</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.first-class {
background: purple;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}
.first-class > .second-class {
background: inherit;
font-weight:normal;
color:black;
}
```